# How can I install software I've downloaded?

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu for the first time and I would like to install some software:  Plink, Genecluster, Meta, Pyenv and Bioconductor.

Most of them have been downloaded and unpacked in my home directory.

When I try to use `apt-get`, for example trying a command like

```
sudo apt-get install plink-core genecluster-core meta-core pyenv-core bioconductor-core
```

I got this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package plink-core
E: Unable to locate package genecluster-core 
E: Unable to locate package meta-core 
E: Unable to locate package pyenv-core 
E: Unable to locate package bioconductor-core
```

Could someone tell me how to proceed with these installations?

Comment: Have you tried installing these packages from inside R?

Answer (score 1):

While `apt-get install PACKAGE-NAME` is the usual way to install software in Ubuntu, in this case it is not the way to go. Notice I wrote 'PACKAGE-NAME' this implies an identifier within a repository, say for example 'gimp'. `apt-get` is used to download and install packages from the repositories, however you have allready downloaded and unpacked (from another source) the files.

A short search on google seems to indicate to me, that the 'software' you are referring to are files which are meant to be run with the statistics software R. Please follow the instructions of the respective webpages on how to use these files or check the manual of R on how to source files.